# How to check return data correctly in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to check the user info by passing user id ! I coded it on `Sch` object function with ajax but return data is always `true` ! I need is true or false return according to return api id.

```
var status = Sch.checkOwner(23); //assume this user is owner => expect return true
var status = Sch.checkOwner(13); //assume this user is not owner => expect return false

var Sch = {
        checkOwner : function(ownerId,data=null){
        if(data != null) {
            return data;
        }
        var owner = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: API_SERVER + '/v1/me',
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: callback
        });
        // ajax response = {id:23};
        function callback(o) {
            if(o.id !== ownerId){
                owner = false;
            }
            Sch.checkOwner(ownerId,owner);
        }       
    }
};
```

> I also check other similar questions but didn't solve mine ! I want to implement by only ajax